# Stub a setter on RSpec instance_double

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

In an RSpec unit test I have a mock defined like this:

```
let(:point) { instance_double("Point", :to_coords => [3,2]) }
```

In the Point class I also have a setter, which is used in the class under test (which is called `Robot`). I would like to stub that setter to test `Robot#move`. Here's the wrong code I have so far:

```
describe "#move" do
  it "sets @x and @y one step forward in the direction the robot is facing" do
    point.stub(:coords=).and_return([4,2])
    robot.move
    expect(robot.position).to eq([4,2])
  end
end
```

Here's the error message I get:

`Double "Point (instance)" received unexpected message :stub with (:coords=)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Got it! The correct syntax looks like this:

```
allow(point).to receive(:coords=).and_return([4,2])
```

The `stub` method is apparently deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to stub the setter method in the definition of the double like so:

```
let(:point) { double("point", 'coords=' => [4,2]) }
```

See [this github issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/458) for details.